# Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/schematics/tasks'

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

when I try to add `@angular/material` to my project I get this error.
*Using Angular Cli: 7.2.1, Node 11.6.0*

> Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/schematics/tasks'
>      Error: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/schematics/tasks'
>      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules  /cjs/loader.js:603:15)
>      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:25)
>      at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:17)
>      at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
>      at Object. (/Users/ricardobaeza/Projects/node_modules/@angular/material/schematics/ng-add/index.js:10:17)
>      at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:30)
>      at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
>      at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
>      at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
>      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)

Comment: run this command `npm i @angular-devkit/schematics`

Comment: @Abhishek I went ahead and used that command and im still gettting that error

Comment: clear your cache

Comment: @Abhishek I cleared the cache with `npm cache clear --force` then I tried `rm -r node_modules/`  `npm i` but no luck

Comment: ok try this `@angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations`

Comment: that fixed it thank you

Comment: ok i'm adding this answer for future help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `@angular/material` command is not install all the dependency currently that why throw error try to run `@angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations` install angular material.

For old version use:-

```
npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations
```

For latest version use:-

```
ng add @angular/material
```

For more information visit official site of angular material https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

`The ng add command will install Angular Material, the Component Dev Kit (CDK), Angular Animations and ask you the following questions to determine which features to include`

Edit:
fixed dashes for npm install command

Comment: What does it mean? could you explain better what should we do?

Comment: do you mean ```npm install @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations```?

Comment: @Vinni  If you are using old version of  `Angular Material` then yes `npm install — save @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations` or if you are using updated version of  `Angular Material` then run `ng add @angular/material`.

Comment: ok but the point is that I started right now a new Angular project (9.1.4) and when I try to    
 run  ```ng add @angular/material ```                                                                                   I get this error: ``` Skipping installation: Package already installed
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/schematics/tasks' ``` I really don't understand what should I do.

Comment: @Vinni Have you tried to remove node_module, cache clean command, i`npm i` and after all this run `ng add @angular/material`

Comment: same issue. I really don't know why.

Answer (score 11):

This is happening because of your **node_modules** does not contain the **material** directory.

To add Material into your node_modules run below command

```
npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations hammerjs
```

After this, you can run below command

```
ng add @angular/material
```

Comment: this still leaves me with an absurd amount of errors. I cant use any components.  After doing this My console is literally overrun with errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, I was building the project from the scratch. For me what I did wrong is I was trying to run

```
ng add @angular/material
```

Before running the

```
npm install
```

Once I ran the "**npm install**" first and then tried to install materials, everything started to install properly without any issues. Its a very silly basic mistake which is worth to note for beginers like me :)

Answer (score 0):

You should try below command:

```
npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations
```